# Accidentally deleted important files from MELOPERO RP2040

Tags: pi-2

I am a beginner in this field... I was trying to edit files from VS Code and I accidentally deleted all the files from my MELOPERO Cookie RP2040 and I cannot access it anymore... Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: `I cannot access it` ... what does that mean? ...what happens? ... what did you try?

Comment: I deleted files named "INDEX.HTM" and "INFO-UF2.HTML" while I was deleting a Micropython file that I was writing in Visual Studio Code... After that the RP2040 denied me every access and now the PC can't read it (the RP2040) anymore.

Comment: INFO-UF2.TXT not INFO-UF2.HTML

Comment: But VS code if not for Pico newbies. Have you set up yourself the IDE for C/C++ as described in this tutorial? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=55iPBJgxN4U.  Unless you must use C/C++, I would recommend to start with Thonny IDE for microPython which does not require any complicated setting up.

Comment: I can't setup anything now because my RP2040 doesn't appear in the connected devices in my PC

Answer (score 1):

Ok I solved the problem, I spammed RESET and BOOTSEL Button on the board to recreate the files and now it's like new.